# How can I use wxFreeChart in wxHaskell?

Tags: haskell, wxhaskell

I'm newbie to haskell.

while [wxFreeChart page in wxCode](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/components/freechart/) says it supports all wx ports, I have no any idea about how to use it in haskell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a C++ library, so you'd have to bind it yourself if you want to use it from Haskell; this is unlikely to be practical, as binding C++ libraries to Haskell is a difficult task. (Indeed, wxHaskell itself is based on a custom "binding" of wxWidgets to pure C.)

You should probably figure out another way to accomplish the same task, or if you really need to use wxFreeChart, write your GUI directly in C++. You could still use Haskell for the core logic using the FFI.

wxWidgets ports aren't relevant here; they're the parts that glue wxWidgets to a windowing system like Windows, GTK+, etc.

If you're not overly tied to wxWidgets, you could check out the [Chart](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Chart) library, which can be [used with Gtk2Hs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Chart-gtk). I haven't used it myself, but it seems [quite polished](http://dockerz.net/twd/HaskellCharts#head-c297f2ffc73f929af9edced8b2d42f6159ca3385).

Comment: is it hard or easy to do so?is there any imformation for binding a lib? I'd like to try binding it

Comment: Binding C++ libraries to Haskell is *very* difficult; as my updated post says, it basically involves writing your own C binding to the library. Then you have to import that C binding with the FFI (probably using [hsc2hs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.2/html/users_guide/hsc2hs.html) or [c2hs](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/haskell/c2hs/)), write wrappers around it to make it usable with Haskell... even then, I'm not sure you'd be able to get it working with wxHaskell, as you won't necessarily be able to get at the underlying wxWidgets types you need to pass to wxFreeChart.

Comment: I would definitely not recommend attempting to write a binding for a C++ library to a newbie :)

Comment: alright, thanks for answering. I'll read something about FFI then.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an author of wxFreeChart. Under "All ports" i meant, Windows, MacOS X, Gtk+, Universal ports.

wxHaskell is not directly supported, and there are no plans to support it. If wxFreeChart will work with wxHaskell, it's great. But, i'm not sure about it.